# How can I register a command in a user control that also applies to the hosting window or rest of the application

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I am writing a user control and I have a requirement to define "hotkeys". This could be for example: Ctrl+S to save the control layout as bitmap. But they are supposed to be application global.
I found out that I can define a command like this in my user control:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"
    Key="{Binding ExitCommand.GestureKey}"
    Modifiers="{Binding ExitCommand.GestureModifier}" />
```

The bindings are from my own Command object and it works. But only in the control (or if it has focus).
How can I declare something that will also work for the hosting application globally?
Or if not in xaml could I code something without knowing the rest of the application?
Or can this only be done from the application level?

Comment: If the hot keys are going to be global, I don't think I would be a good idea to define them in the UserControl.

Comment: I know its not the smartest idea but the user control does not really have a visual focus. And the user can set the hotkeys in the attached config boxes (so inside of the user control). So either it is catching the keys in the application or the user has a hard time getting the focus to the user control.

Comment: But saying that and thinking about your comment: I could possibly hand in a settings class from the application to the control and the control could register its hotkeys in there. Then I would have to do the keyboard bindings in code. But the application could manage hotkeys in case there are more than the ones from the user control.

Comment: I agree with @MehrzadChehraz's comment. It's bad form for a component to even want to globally force a shortcut key on the application, never mind actually do so. What if your chosen key conflicts with something else the application legitimately wants it to do? IMHO, for global behavior maybe better to just expose `ICommand` objects (e.g. as static fields, a la `ApplicationCommands`), and let the application use a `KeyBinding` to set the shortcut key.

Comment: Its a requirement that I do want to talk about with product owner. But it is always better to say "I know how to do it but I recommend against it" than to say "I don't know how to do it but we shouldn't do it anyway". So this question is also for my knowledge and arguments if it is possible to do or not. If it is not possible at all thats fine as well. Its an answer to the question. Then I can say its not possible.